# Pivot top 100 rows into columns for all tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My mission is to get top 100 rows from all my tables in a database, and union them into one result output.
Since the tables have varying columncount and varying types, the only way I see to do this is to put the row number as columns, and the column name in the first column. Row 1 from all tables will then be represented in column 2 and so forth.

My skills in SQL aren't good enough to figure this one out, so I hope the community can assist me in this.

Here is some code:

```
--Example table
create table Worker (Id int, FirstName nvarchar(max));


--Some data
insert into Worker values (1,'John'),(2,'Jane'),(3,'Elisa');

--Static pivot example
select * from (select
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id) as IdRows, FirstName  from worker) as st
pivot
(
    max(FirstName) for IdRows in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pt;

--Code to incorporate to get column name on column 1
select name from sys.columns where object_id('Worker') = object_id;

--Cleanup
drop table Worker;
```

I reckon the static pivot must be dynamic, which is not a problem. The above code is just to create a proof of concept, so I have something to build further on.

End result of query should be like this:

```
Column      1       2       3
FirstName   John    Erina   Jane
```

I hope this can be solved without using cursors and temp tables, but maybe that's the way to go?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, I'm using sqlserver (mssql)

EDIT2:
I'm not all that good at explaining, so here is some more code to do that job for me.
This will add another column to Worker table, and a query to show the desired result. It's the query that has to be "smarter" so it can handle future added tables and columns added. (again, this is a proof of concept. The database has > 200 tables and > 1000 columns)

```
--Add a column
alter table Worker add LastName nvarchar(max);
--Add some data
update Worker set LastName = 'Smith' where Id = 1;
update Worker set LastName = 'Smith' where Id = 2;
update Worker set LastName = 'Smith' where Id = 3;

--Query to give desired output (top 100, but only 3 rows in this table)
select 'FirstName' as 'Column',* from (select top 100 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id) as IdRows, FirstName  from worker) as st
pivot
(
    max(FirstName) for IdRows in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pt
union
select 'LastName' as 'Column',* from (select top 100 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id) as IdRows, LastName  from worker) as st
pivot
(
    max(LastName) for IdRows in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pt
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: you mean dynamic pivoting and seems you're using SQL Server as @jarlh pointed out. So [**SQL Server** dynamic **pivot** query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) may help.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, Making it into a dynamic query is quite easy. The problem is pivoting it properly when I don't know how many columns there are, and how many tables there are in the database.
Also everything has to be converted to nvarchar on the fly, since there will be dates, boolean, int, decimal, etc in a mix in each column after pivoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I used temp table, and put it into a loop. Not a good solution, but it works. Had to cast all the data to nvarchar to make it work.